# Width of the text in pixels (Powershell GUI)

Tags: powershell

Does Powershell have a special method for determining the length of a string in pixels (in this case, the width of the text is determined automatically using ".AutoSize = $True")? Or should I know the width of one character and then multiply by the length of the string? For example, the text has the font Arial 14px.

```
$StackOverflow = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$StackOverflow.AutoSize = $True
$StackOverflow.Font = 'Arial, 14px, Style=Regular'
$StackOverflow.Text = 'Thank you for helping me learn the Powershell syntax!'
```

Ideally, if there is a method similar to this:

```
$StackOverflow.TextWidth() # Width of the text in pixels

PS> 371
```

And what if it is for example Chinese?

```
$StackOverflow.Text = '感謝您幫助我學習Powershell語法。'
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The .net framework has a “MeasureString” method you can use for this, and you can call .net methods from PowerShell with a bit of coaxing... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mclayton's hints, I found the answer ([link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3843ddcc-e326-4e5e-808c-59abd4d4dcea/find-the-length-of-a-string-in-pixels?forum=winserverpowershell)) and write it for those who need it.

```
$String = 'Thank you for helping me learn the Powershell syntax!'
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Arial', 14)
$Size = [System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer]::MeasureText($String, $Font)

$Size.Width
```